# How to select individual checkboxes from dynamic set of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm trying to implement the individual checkbox selection from a list of dynamically generated checkboxes and also when I check the checkbox at h6 level (selectAll() method) all the individual checkboxes should be checked.

How can I achieve this? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
this.services.getData().subscribe(result => {
  if(result.success) {
    this.setData = result.data.values;
  }
});

selectedData(pos, event) {
  
}

selectAll(event) {

}
```

```html
<div class="data-info">
   <h6><input type="checkbox" (click)="selectAll($event)" class="header-checkbox">Info()</h6>
    <table>                    
      <tr *ngFor="let data of setData; let i = index">
        <td class="table-data">
          <p-checkbox binary="true" class="user-checkbox" (change)="selectedData(i, $event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedData"></p-checkbox>
          <span class="user-values">{{data.value}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>                    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to try angular material checkbox.
https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox

so then, you can use a variable to check/uncheck them via checked output from their API.

```
 <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? toggle(item, $event) : null"
                   [checked]="item.isChecked" >
      {{item.value}}
    </mat-checkbox>
```

Then you could use map from rxjs to change / initialize field isChecked for each item (at the beginning they all should be false, maybe just one true - if you want default)

```
selectAll(event) {

// foreach item => isChecked = true
}

selectedData(pos, event) {
  //find the item you want to check and isChecked = false, rest of the fields should have isChecked = true (if you want unique on checked)
}
```

Comment: {{item.value}} sorry*